# Border image for CardView in Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-cardview

Please forgive me if I am presenting it wrong or my way of asking this question is wrong, but I have a question on how to set an image as the border of the CardView in Android. Below is border image which i want to set border as for the Cardview.

[image]

Below is the code of my layout.

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/card_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="60"
        card_view:cardBackgroundColor="#1a6ee8"
        card_view:cardCornerRadius="5dp"
        card_view:cardElevation="5dp"
        card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="true">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <FrameLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

                <me.zhanghai.android.materialprogressbar.MaterialProgressBar
                    android:id="@+id/progressView"
                    style="@style/Widget.MaterialProgressBar.ProgressBar.Large"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:indeterminate="true" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/dailyKolam"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                    android:scaleType="fitXY" />
            </FrameLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:background="@drawable/gradient_header"
                android:padding="16dp">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:text="@string/kolamDay"
                    android:textColor="#fff"
                    android:textSize="18sp" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </RelativeLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Comment: Do you have border image? If yes then put cardview in to linear layout and apply background to linear layout.

Comment: cardView is coming over the image which i have posted above after putting the cardView inside the linear layout.

Comment: Do you want the border image inside the `CardView` or do you want the image to go around the `CardView`? A picture of what you want to do would help.

Comment: the border image should go around the cardView.

Answer (score 0):

> Wrap your whole layout in `FramLayout` set frame as background image to `FramLayout` use padding as match edges with frame image

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="60"
    android:background="@drawable/frame_border">

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/card_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        card_view:cardBackgroundColor="#1a6ee8"
        card_view:cardCornerRadius="5dp"
        card_view:cardElevation="5dp"
        android:padding="20sdp">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <FrameLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

                <me.zhanghai.android.materialprogressbar.MaterialProgressBar
                    android:id="@+id/progressView"
                    style="@style/Widget.MaterialProgressBar.ProgressBar.Large"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:indeterminate="true" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/dailyKolam"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                    android:scaleType="fitXY" />
            </FrameLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:background="@drawable/gradient_header"
                android:padding="16dp">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:text="@string/kolamDay"
                    android:textColor="#fff"
                    android:textSize="18sp" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </RelativeLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
</FrameLayout>
```